# Creating a Google Analytics report on how many pageviews for a page came via another page

Tags: google-analytics

Our site runs Google Analytics and we want to find the pageviews of

- a set of content pages - identifiable with a page title regex
- visitors that came through a certain section listing page - identifiable with a page title fragment

There will be an intermediate category listing page between this one and the content page, so the navigation path goes like this:

> → [wherever] → section listing page → click → category listing page → click → content page.

I'm not really interested in the middle category page, just how many pageviews to these content pages had that section page somewhere back in their navigation history, if you see what I mean.

I have been grappling with GA for the last couple of days but despite a couple of promising leads regarding landing pages/page path levels I have not been able to get the stats needed.

Has anyone done anything similar that they are able to provide some hints as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Goal.
You can do that on your account settings page.
Then with the goal you can select differnt steps.

Maybe that helps?

Comment: Please elaborate. Your answer is vague and it doesn't fit with WA's format. Cheers!

Comment: Actually there is not much more to it. Just give it a try. With Goals you can crate a funnel. E.g. entry page, page 1, page 2, end page. And then see how many people followed this path.

Comment: That does seem to be the way to go - the funnel visualisation in particular is useful. Have set up two possible ways to get to a sample content page from the set I am interested in, will give it a few days and see what my users are actually doing. Thanks again.